# Commutative matrices in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ commute then we can certainly say that $A^T$ and $B^T$ commute as by taking the transpose of $AB$ which is $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ will prove that. Can we prove the same for $A^T$ and $B$? If so then how?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 2):

If you take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
then $AB = BA$ but $A^\top B\neq BA^\top$.